# Why does anchor not work with Controls.Add?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm still learning Visual Studio 2013, C# and Windows Forms. So, bear with me!

I added a button to a form. I also added a new custom user control that contained another form with a button. I wanted to add an event on click that loads and deloads this new custom user control.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(this.MyHomePanel);

    }
```

This code does just that simply enough. On click, it loads the MyHomePanel user control. However, the anchor properties of that control do not load when all other properties do. Properties that do load is the default position, the background image I set and the border. The anchor tags such as Top, Bottom and Left do not seem to be loading.

```
this.MyHomePanel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
```

This puzzles me because the Anchor code is right if I manually drew it in the form versus when I remove the manual draw and call it with Controls.Add();. This also puzzles me because the other properties also load with no issues.

Comment: Replace the `|` with `&`

Comment: Why do you use Winforms and not WPF?

Comment: Why shouldn't he use WinForms?

Comment: TomTom, it's not recognizing the anchor code at all, but it does recognize all other properties just fine. The code itself was put there by Visual Studio automatically when I manually drew the form to the designer. I just removed the Controls.Add code from InitializeComponent(); and added it to the Click event.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the automated generated code.

Comment: @BartoszWójtowicz There is nothing wrong with Windows Forms. WPF fonts are blurry still, when you scroll, they're blurry, WPF is slower to startup, WPF requires a far greater learning curve than Windows Forms. And you say, "What about binding?" Yeah, Windows Forms has binding too, and I found it easier to create my own classes and objects that autosync everything in winforms before I even finished learning the basics of WPF. WPF is a time waster for most things I would create. The only real benefit for me in using WPF is it's lightyears faster when youre adding lots of controls to a Window

Comment: I'm just starting with WinForms. No need to start a war lol.

Comment: Hello again @HighCore :)

Comment: @Aeron please show me how your `"own classes and objects to autosync everything"` do the equivalent of this: `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDataModel.NestedProperty.SomeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: @Aeron or this: `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>`

Comment: @Aeron and regarding blurry fonts, simply force the scroll offset to integer values, the blur is caused by non-integer pixel independent units being rendered with antialias. So a scroll offset of, say, 10.3434 is going to cause a blurry font. Either that or disable antialiasing and you're good to go. Whereas the retardedness and uselessness of winforms have no possible workarounds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried it by myself and it works with:

```
this.MyHomePanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Left;
```

Comment: Did you define this in  InitializeComponent();?

Comment: No, I created it in the cs-File after `InitializeComponent`

Comment: Do this for me. Maybe it's how I'm creating it. Create a new form. Add a button. Add a panel beside that button with Anchors. Go into designer.cs and comment out the this.Controls.Add(this.panel1); Then go back into the designer, double-click on the button and add that code to the click event and run. The panel properties are set in InitializeComponent(); still, but loading to the form is commented out and placed in the Click Event. Why is that not working?

Comment: Working the way I told you to try it? Because it's surely not working on my end. :D

Comment: What are you expecting? I gave the panel a Background-Color to see it during runtime. After I click the button, the panel appears

Comment: When I click the button, the panel appears. It's just not anchored to the bottom. I'm expecting an anchor. :)

Comment: I have the anchor with your way

Comment: Looks like it is anchoring, just not to the bottom of the form/screen sigh.

Comment: If you change the height of your form, the panel doesn't change?

Comment: seriously? bitwise AND & instead of bitwise OR | results in zero, which is simply `AnchorStyles.None`.